# If I use a fixed formula in a #define, is it less efficient than using a number?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, cortex-m

I am working my way through some legacy code at work for a Cortex-M3, written in C on Keil µVision.

In a function to record values from an ADC, a scaling factor is used to convert from bits back to volts.

My question revolves around the scaling factor, which is defined in the header file:

`#define INPUT_VALUE_MAX    (uint16_t)((1<<12)-1)`

So this equals 4095, which makes sense, because it is a 12-bit ADC. The question I have is whether defining the value "INPUT_VALUE_MAX" as a formula means that every time it is used, the microcontroller has to re-calculate the value.

Simply, does:

`#define INPUT_VALUE_MAX    (uint16_t)((1<<12)-1)`

take more processing time than:

`#define INPUT_VALUE_MAX    (uint16_t)4095`?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: According to the compiler used, it rewrite the first like the second for optimisation so I think it is the same.

Comment: (Almost?) all compilers will evaluate the constant at compile-time and just stick `4095` into the code.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you both for your speedy and helpful responses!

Comment: The only way to be sure is to look at the assembly code your compiler generates. But integer optimization is what compilers have been good at for very long, so you'd have to have a weird compiler if it is not able to optimize that.

Comment: Also, to be safe, you should add an extra set of parentheses around your constant. Althogh, in your case you'd have to do use your macro very weirdly, to get unintended behavior.

Comment: Here is an example of uninteded behavior, because of missing parentheses: http://ideone.com/XGom74

Comment: @chtz Anyone writing code like that deserve all the bugs they can get :) But generally it is indeed wise to cover macros with parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you all for the great help!

Comment: Note that the choice of `(1<<12)-1` over `4095` is very likely for human readability. It's easier to see that the value is 12 bits wide and all 1's from the former than from the latter.

Comment: Thanks Sander, I assumed that might be the reason. I can see the logic in that, and if it doesn't impact the execution time, it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not take any run-time processing time. The whole macro is an *integer constant expression*, meaning it will get calculated at compile-time.

If you look at the generated assembly, you'll see that the expression is replaced by the constant 4095.

---

A constant expression is defined by C like this, C11 6.6:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than
> runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may
> be.
>
> Constraints
>
> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.
>
> Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable
> values for its type.

/--/

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, _Alignof expressions, and floating constants that are the
> immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
> expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types,
> except as part of an operand to the sizeof or _Alignof operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!